# Animating particular section of the screen

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am creating a view based application. I have an image in this app and I have to cut a particular section of the image and animate it little up and down.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: cut the image in two, place them in two UIImageView, animate the part of image you need. what about that?

Answer (score 1):

set imageview frame and wrirte these two line
[imageview commitanimation]
[imageview setanimationduration:1]

Answer (score 0):

You should duplicated your image and crop it (have a look at [this post](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-crop-an-image.html)), then you put the resulting image in a UIImageView or CALayer and animate it as you like.